# SQLSTATE[23505]: Unique violation In-spite of ID set to auto_increment

Tags: laravel, postgresql

I have created migration from the PHP artisan command and it had created a table in my Postgres database, with id set to `auto_increment`.

I have made some seeder in laravel and three rows of data are fed to the previously created table through php artisan db:seed command.

When I am inserting data through some form in the same table, it is giving me an error.

```
error:SQLSTATE[23505]: Unique violation: 7 ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "roles_pkey" DETAIL: Key (id)=(1) already exists. (SQL: insert into "roles" ("name", "guard_name", "updated_at", "created_at") values (staff, web, 2019-07-03 07:38:37, 2019-07-03 07:38:37) returning "id")
```

Comment: can you post your migration?

Comment: as the error says id=1 already exists... make sure you don't have duplicates rows. provide some code to help you

Comment: If you manually specify "auto_increment" column for INSERT statement in PostgreSQL then sequence won't be used and thus will remain at "1". My guess is that this tool you used to generate random data ignored the fact that you configured your table to use database built-in identity mechanisms and went ahead with something else.

Comment: @jycr753 `public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('themes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->integer('user_id');
            $table->string('theme_code');
            $table->string('theme_name');
            $table->integer('sequence');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }`

Answer (score 2):

Sequences are objects that return a value that is one greater on each request, regardless of which transaction it was called on. A sequence by default starts at 1 and can be applied to a table, or many tables, so it cannot know how many values there are in your table already. If you want your insert to work you will need to manually set it.

```
SELECT setval('roles_id_seq', (SELECT coalesce((SELECT max(id) from roles),1)))
```

This query is assuming that the sequence used was created on the column `"id"` on the `"roles"` table, if not the sequence name can be found by checking that columns DDL e.g. `NOT NULL DEFAULT setval('the_sequence_name')` and use that to set the value.

Comment: I have previously manually done this setval in Postgres many times, but I want to know why I am getting an error when I am initially setting primary key as a unique and auto increment.

then adding data through seeder,
id-1,id-2,id-3 is created.

Then any further data should be id-4, but why it is assigning id as 1.

Comment: This is possibly an issue with the seeder, maybe the sequence was added after the table was created and data inserted.